# Fixed width and height to fit text in css?

Tags: html, css

How would I make a div fix the width and height to the amount it needs, for example like Bootstrap does? for its buttons..

```css
body {
        background-color: #f8f9fb;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    /* Buttons... */
    .button {
        padding: 10px 10px;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .green-button {
        background-color: #2cd865;
    }
    
    .green-button:hover {
        background-color: #61dc7a
    }
```

```html
Buttons.. idk<br>
 <div onclick="alert('hey');" class="button green-button">Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap buttons have *fixed* height by defining `padding` and `font-size`. However, it does not have *fixed* width. Please check http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons, the width of the buttons changes according to the text inside the button.

To *fix* the width of buttons, you can make `.button` as `inline-block` and define `width` for it.

Here is an example which have fixed width and height:

```
.button {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Please note as the button width and height is fixed, if the text inside button is too long, some part of text will be hidden.

If the button need to *expand* automatically when text inside it is too long, `min-width` can be used:

```
.button {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine min-width and max-width in your css. This example will set the width to 100px.

```
.button {
    max-width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
 }
```

Here's a link to W3 schools in which you may try it out live on their site.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dim_max-width